# Pasar datos de un csv a una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un csv parecido al siguiente:

```
ID;texto
1;Los niños comen sardinas
2;Los pájaros vuelan alto porque tienen alas
3;Érase una vez la vida
4;Un 67% de los adultos vive en la pobreza
```

Deseo leer el csv y extraer la columa texto. Me gustaría que los comentarios de texto estuvieran recogidos en una lista. He intentado esto:

```
import csv
import codecs
with codecs.open("Libro1.csv", "r") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, dialect='unix', delimiter = ";")
    list =[]
    for row in reader:
        list.append(row["c"])
        print (list)
```

Comment: Si te pasea adecuadamente el archivo con `list.append(row["texto"])` dentro del `for`  te retorna la lista sin problemas. ¿que error o problema tienes? El `print` tienes que sacarlo del `for` para que imprima la lista completa una sola vez.

Comment: Gracias. Errores de principiante... ains... gracias!

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo.
Entiendo que la idea que tenía era correcta, el problema venía porque el comando print lo tenía dentro del loop.
Así sí obtengo la lista correctamente:

```
import csv
import codecs
with codecs.open("Libro1.csv", "r") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, dialect='unix', delimiter = ";")
    list =[]
    for row in reader:
        list.append(row["c"])
print (list)
```